# How to list all +1 of Google+ user

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-plus

I don't know how to list all +1 of specific person from Google+ in JavaScript - I searched on Google+ API site, but I couldn't find it. Do you know any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The API doesn't provide this feature yet.

Comment: Do you know if and when Google is planning to add this feature?